# undefined reference to pthread create even with lpthread

Tags: c++, linker, g++, pthreads

I want to make use of `pthread` ad hence use the `-lpthread` flag to compile, but here's what I get:

```
$ g++ -lpthread pseudo_code.cpp 
/tmp/cc3mPrvt.o: In function `MyThreadClass::StartInternalThread()':
pseudo_code.cpp:(.text._ZN13MyThreadClass19StartInternalThreadEv[_ZN13MyThreadClass19StartInternalThreadEv]+0x26): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code I try to compile is below:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#define OK      0
#define ERROR   -1

//-- ThreadClass
class MyThreadClass
{
public:
   MyThreadClass() {/* empty */}
   virtual ~MyThreadClass() {/* empty */}

   /** Returns true if the thread was successfully started, false if there was an error starting the thread */
   bool StartInternalThread()
   {
      return (pthread_create(&_thread, NULL, InternalThreadEntryFunc, this) == 0);
   }

   /** Will not return until the internal thread has exited. */
   void WaitForInternalThreadToExit()
   {
      (void) pthread_join(_thread, NULL);
   }

protected:
   /** Implement this method in your subclass with the code you want your thread to run. */
   virtual void InternalThreadEntry() = 0;

private:
   static void * InternalThreadEntryFunc(void * This) {
       ((MyThreadClass *)This)->InternalThreadEntry(); return NULL;
       }

   pthread_t _thread;
};
//-- /ThreadClass
//--- DUMMY DECLARATIONS BELOW TO MAKE IT COMPILE ---//
#define LOG_NS_ERROR std::cout
class test{
    public:
        int get_child(std::string x){return OK;};
};
test *_global;
typedef struct test_struct{} _db_transact;
class db_transact{
    public: 
        db_transact(int,int&,int&){};
};
int _ns;
int _log_id;
//--- DUMMY DECLARATIONS ABOVE TO MAKE IT COMPILE ---//
class db_c_hndlr : public MyThreadClass{
    public: 
        db_c_hndlr(void);
        ~db_c_hndlr(void);
        db_transact *db_conn_get(void);
        void InternalThreadEntry(void *func);
    private:
        int _stop;
        std::vector<db_transact*> _db_pool;
};
//---------------------------------------------------------

db_c_hndlr::db_c_hndlr(void) {
}
//---------------------------------------------------------

void db_c_hndlr::InternatThreadEntry(void *func) {

    while(!stop){
        std::cout << "going!" << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------

db_c_hndlr::~db_c_hndlr() {
    int i = 0;
    std::vector<db_transact*>::iterator it;
    for (i=0, it = _db_pool.begin();it!=_db_pool.end();it++, i++) {
        if (_db_pool[i])
            if (_db_pool[i]!=NULL) 
                delete _db_pool[i];
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------

db_transact *db_c_hndlr::db_conn_get(void) {
    db_transact *tmp;

    tmp = new db_transact(_global->get_child("db_config"), _ns, _log_id);
    _db_pool.push_back(tmp);
    return tmp;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------
int main(void)
{
    db_transact *conn=NULL;
    db_c_hndlr db;
    //db = new db_c_hndlr();

    conn= db.db_conn_get();
    return OK;
}
```

Comment: Use `-pthread` not `-lpthread`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck if you add this as an answer, i'll accept. I've got to find out why this is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to do this:

```
extern "C" {
#include <pthread.h>
}
```

That tells the compiler that this header is for a C library, and that it should not use C++ name mangling.

You also need to use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`, because the pthread library is special and GCC wants to explicitly know you are trying to use threads, not simply link against libpthread.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to compile with the command.

```
g++ pseudo_code.cpp -lpthread
```

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the
>   linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order
>   they are specified.  Thus, foo.o  -lz bar.o searches library z after
>   file foo.o but before bar.o.  If bar.o refers to functions in z, those
>   functions may not be loaded.

It worked for me. It seems, needs to specify the library after the source file so that symbols are searched in the library.